# Rationalize Below Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I rationalize the following equation:

$$\frac{22}{4\sqrt[3]{9}+2\sqrt[3]{6}+\sqrt[3]{4}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a=2\sqrt[3]{3}, b=\sqrt[3]{2}$. Then this is equal to $\dfrac{22}{a^2+ab+b^2} = \dfrac{22(a-b)}{a^3-b^3}$.

Since $a^3-b^3 = 8(3)-2 =22$, we have that our desired answer is $\dfrac{22(a-b)}{a^3-b^3} = a-b = 2\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Comment: This one really requires a bit more attention than most. Nicely done.